# pydoc.doc fail to retrieve the "os.path.sep"

Tags: python, pydoc

I check the help utility with `os.path.sep` in the interactive mode and come by:

```
In [59]: help(os.path.sep)
Related help topics: lambda, or, and, not, in, is, BOOLEAN, COMPARISON,BITWISE, SHIFTING, BINARY, FORMATTING, POWER, UNARY, ATTRIBUTES,SUBSCRIPTS, SLICINGS, CALLS, TUPLES, LISTS, DICTIONARIES
```

> Operator precedence
>
> ---
>
> The following table summarizes the operator precedence in Python, from
>   lowest precedence (least binding) to highest precedence (most
>   binding).  Operators in the same box have the same precedence.  Unless
>   the syntax is explicitly given, operators are binary.  Operators in
>   the same box group left to right (except for exponentiation, which
>   groups from right to left).

However, when I try to retrieve it with pydoc

```
In [61]: with open("osPathSep_help.md", "w") as fout:
    ...:     pydoc.doc(os.path.sep, output=fout)
    ...:     
No Python documentation found for '/'.
Use help() to get the interactive help utility.
Use help(str) for help on the str class.

In [62]: os.stat("osPathSep_help.md").st_size
Out[62]: 0
```

How to get the same content as the quotation?

> The following table summarizes the operator precedence in Python, from
>   lowest precedence (least binding) to highest precedence (most

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand this behaviour you have to get inside the `os.path` library source code. If you go inside the code then you will find all these variables

```
curdir = '.'
pardir = '..'
extsep = '.'
sep = '\\'
pathsep = ';'
altsep = '/'
defpath = '.;C:\\bin'
devnull = 'nul'
```

Now what you are trying to do is access `os.path.sep` as a function but as you can see it is not a function but a variable with a value assigned as **'\'**

So os.path.sep is always `\` , thats why when you are doing `help(os.path.sep)` you are getting the result as

> Operator precedence
>
> The following table summarizes the operator precedence in Python, from
>   lowest precedence (least binding) to highest precedence (most
>   binding). Operators in the same box have the same precedence. Unless
>   the syntax is explicitly given, operators are binary. Operators in the
>   same box group left to right (except for exponentiation, which groups
>   from right to left).

Which will the same result as you will get when you would do

```
help('\\')
```

Now your next question would be how does it work with `help`?

so if you check the source code of help it is mentioned

```
"""
Define the built-in 'help'.
This is a wrapper around pydoc.help (with a twist).
"""
```

So help is internally using `pydoc.help`

So if you are using

`pydoc.help('\\')` or `pydoc.help(os.path.sep)` you would get your desired output.